# elasticsearch create TransportConnection timeout

Tags: java, elasticsearch, timeout

I am creating a Elasticsearch Connection with Java API. I am using TransportConnection and I need to set the timeout for the connection.

I haven't configured any property and the connect takes three minutes to give me a timeout.

Anybody know if any property exists to set the value of timeout?

Thaks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", cluster_name).put("client.transport.ping_timeout", "30s").build();

    TransportClient transport = new TransportClient(settings);
```

See also the following from ES documentation page:

[Fault Detection](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-discovery-zen.html#fault-detection)

Comment: The page that you link to for elastic 2.4 calls out discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout.  Should I be doing: 
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", cluster_name).put("discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout", "30s").build();

Comment: The answer refers to Elasticsearch 1.7 (fixed the link), see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-discovery-zen.html#fault-detection

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  For anyone else who is curious I had to add .put("transport.tcp.connect_timeout", "5s") to change my timeout

Comment: @Grammin Thanks for the update. Please add the Elasticsearch version that you used in you comment (this will help others when testing).

Comment: This was ES 2.3. No problem!

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below to update the TransportClient's connection time out value:

```
Settings.builder().put("transport.tcp.connect_timeout", "240s")
```

The Complete TransportClient code:

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
        .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
        .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
        .put("transport.tcp.connect_timeout", "240s")
        .build();

Client transportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddresses(
                new TransportAddress("127.0.0.1"), "9300"));
```

**Important:** Each Elasticsearch version has **different config key**. You can read this document to learn about other settings you can change:

[www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/modules-transport.html](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/modules-transport.html)

If you are using **AWS Elasticsearch**, check the load balancer time out settings.

[docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout)