# No node available exception in Elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am using transport client for ES. I have a search request for 1 million records.

I am getting "No node available" exception after getting 8k records itself.

It is giving `org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException` also sometimes.

What can be done to overcome this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [elasticsearch create TransportConnection timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602499/elasticsearch-create-transportconnection-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the timeout of ES to a higher value.

See related question here: [timeout-es](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602499/elasticsearch-create-transportconnection-timeout/27603609#27603609)